# How to stop stackview from growing beyond tableView cell content view (Programmatic UI)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uistackview

So I've been trying out programmatic UI lately and I'm running into an issue where a `stackView` is out-growing the `UITableViewCell contentView`. Initially, I was getting a `constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero` error so I assigned a height to the `imageView` but not to the `stackview` because I want it to grow depending on its content (in this case, 3 `UIlabels` with `numberOfLines` = 0). That error is gone and the UI looks almost close to what I want but I can't figure out the stackview out-growing issue.

Comment: No pictures of code please. Code is text; copy and paste.

Comment: For future reference, the easiest way to put in a chunk of code like that is by clicking on the {} button on the formatting toolbar.  You can also surround *very short* pieces of code with 3 backticks (`) on each side.

Answer (score 1):

padding is 10 you set bottom Anchor to cell bottom + 10 so you can replace you last line with

```
textContentStackView.bottomAnchor.contraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor,constant: -padding)
```

one more thing is here is you row height matters with stack if your row height is n the stack view height is n-20. so your label's height is stack view height - 10 / 3 because 3 items in stack with 5 padding  . adjust your font size as well

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you statement about the centerYAnchor being important, but you are definitely right about the stack's bottomAnchor.

Comment: yeah I forget that you are giving bottom and top so centerY is useless